# False Resharper suggestion "Use method InstanceOfType"?

Tags: c#, reflection, resharper

The following extension method tries, for a given value of unknown type, to find a constructor with a single parameter such that the constructor can be called with that value.

```
private static ConstructorInfo ConstructorThatTakesValue
    (this Type thisType, object value)
{
    return thisType.GetConstructors().FirstOrDefault(c =>
        c.GetParameters().Count() == 1 &&
        c.GetParameters().First().ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()));
}
```

That is, if `var c = typeof(X).ConstructorThatTakesValue(y)`, then we can create a `x` by

```
var x = (X)c.Invoke(new object[] { y });
```

The code above works like a charm, but Resharper marks the line containing `IsAssignableFrom` and displays "Use method `InstanceOfType`". It also provides a QuickFix which *literally* just replaces `IsAssignableFrom` by `IsInstanceOfType`, which by my intuition is the exact opposite of what I am trying to achieve:

```
c.GetParameters().First().ParameterType.IsInstanceOfType(value.GetType()));
```

Even more suspicious, this message is displayed as a "suggestion", not a warning or so. That is, Resharper seems to consider the change a simple stylistic improvement.

I also tried to gain understanding of the semantics of the two methods, but I was not able to grasp the meaning of documentation on the MSDN either. My understanding would be that if `class A : B`, then `B.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(A.GetType())` and `A.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(B.GetType())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One works with Types and the Other instances, in fact one calls the other:

```
public virtual bool IsInstanceOfType(object o)
{
    if (o == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return this.IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType());
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. Now I finally get to understand the semantics! `A.IsInstanceOfType(B)` means "is the object B an instance of type A". Actually, to make your statement "the Other with instances" slightly more precise, only the parameter is an instance, the object that provides the method represents a Type in both cases.

Comment: Hence also the suggestion of Resharper: By replacing "IsAssignableFrom" by "IsInstanceOfType", we can omit the `.GetType()` and simplify the code a little bit.  Methinks "IsInstanceOfType" is a veeery confusing name for that method since it reads as "A is instance of type B". The name `IsAssignableFrom` is much clearer so I'll stick with it, even if it takes an additional `.GetType()`.

Comment: All of these methods suck in naming and are assured to get the parameter/instance inverted. Apparently it's so common resharper even offers to flip them for you on the lightbulb

Answer (score 1):

Kevin Cooks answer is good, but there is an overlook in Resharper's engine: it does not differenciate from Objects and Types (it treat the Type instance as an Object).

As in, if your B argument is **already** a Type object, it will still ask you to switch to "IsInstanceOf". Which is false and will lead to errors in this very limited context.

EDIT: I double check my test case I founf out it's not longer the case. When the second argument type is indeed Type, it correctly uses the IsAssignableFrom method without warnings.